# How to create this star shape in Adobe Xd?

Tags: vector, layers, shapes, adobe-xd

How can we create star shapes like the one highlighted below, in a simple way?

[image]

Currently, I am taking it this way:

- Creating a circle
- Adding a line around it (with some slight rotation)

Comment: Do you mean the star burst shape? See [Create custom star shapes with the polygon tool](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd/learn/design/tools/create-custom-star-shapes-polygon-tool.html)

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you, it helped :)

Comment: I edited your question to make it more clear, you can [edit] and rollback if it doesn't reflect what you're asking.